# kCFXMLParserSkipWhitespace and text element

Tags: xml, macos, macos-carbon

I am using [`CFXMLParserCreate()`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFXMLParserRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001234-CH1g-F14203) with [`kCFXMLParserSkipWhitespace`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFXMLParserRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCFXMLParserSkipWhitespace) to parse some XML files. The option helps skipping the white spaces between XML tags like the space bwtween <`foo> <bar>` which is good.

However, I just find out that it also caused text elements that contain only white space to be skipped, too. For example, the space between `<Status> </Status>` is skipped.

How do I tell the parse to keep the white space text elements? Thanks.